# .htaccess rewrite Category/page/1

Tags: .htaccess

this is my current code in `.htaccess`

```
# Rewrite for category.php?cat=xxxxx
RewriteRule ^category/([0-9a-zA-Z-]+) category.php?cat=$1&page=$2 [NC,L]
```

I'm getting `category/dog/1`

But how can I achieved like this:
`category/dog/page/1`

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer after reading and testing it;

```
RewriteRule ^category/([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)/page/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) category.php?cat=$1&pagi=$2 [NC,L]
```